# Get children nodes names

Tags: xml, xquery

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<class>
   <student>
      <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>Kad</lastname>
      <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
</class>
```

I want to write an XQuery that return :

```
firstname
lastname
nickname
marks
```

logically this should work :

```
/class/student/*::name()
```

But it doesn't work!
Do you know what is the correct XQuery to get the list of children's node names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the names of the children with the following code:

```
for $nam in doc("source.xml")/class/student/*
return name($nam)
```

Or you can use this more simple expression:

```
/class/student/*/name()
```

This only works with XPath-2.0 which is supported by XQuery 1.0.

Comment: I want one XQuery statement. This is not an XQuery statement.

Comment: I tested it with Saxon. Both expressions do work and return the desired output.

Comment: OK. I want to run it with XML ver 1.0.  we do not have third party libraries.

Comment: when I run **/class/student/*/name()** I get error in notepad++ or VisualStudio.

Comment: XQuery 1.0 should support XPath-2.0 because ["The XQuery and XPath Data Model (XDM) is the data model shared by the XPath 2.0, XSLT 2.0 and XQuery programming languages."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery_and_XPath_Data_Model). If it doesn't, it's not XQuery.